# How is d.get used by max()?

Tags: python, dictionary

The `d.get` method(?) is working fabulously for me to find the max of a value in a dictionary while returning the key. But I can't seem to understand or find any explanation for how `d.get` operates. Is far as I can tell: `max()` iterates over an `iterable` and returns the iteration of greatest value. When iterating over a `dict`, this defaults to assessing the `max` `key`.

My confusion comes from the difference between `d.get` and `d.get(key)`. How can you call a method without `()`? I'm not sure how else to investigate this.

`foo = max(d, key = d.get)`

```
weights = {
 95: 0.0,
 96: 0.0,
 97: 0.30793650793650795,
 98: 0.0,
 99: 0.0,
 100: 0.0,
 101: 0.48095238095238096,
 102: 0.0,
 103: 0.0,
 104: 0.49523809523809526,
 105: 0.0}

heaviest = max(weights, key = weights.get)
--> 104
```

Using the optional argument to [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) one can sort by the `value` and return the `key`. I just don't understand what is being assigned to the `key` argument.

Thanks all.

Comment: All of Python code is available. You could look at the source code. https://github.com/python/

Comment: @dfundako that would be the answer to 100% of pure-python questions, no?

Comment: So you are trying to find out what is assigned to the key? If that's the case, please change the title of your question.

Comment: @roganjosh It just seems like a "How does this work" question would be best described by the actual code that is implementing it. "How do I use this" would be different. The source code would show exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @dfundako come on now :) You know properly that the OP wasn't looking for a link to the source code and nothing else.

Comment: What is assigned to `key` is the bound method `d.get`. Is that what you are asking, or are you asking how `d.get` is *used* by `max`?

Comment: @roganjosh Forgive me. When I see a "under the hood" question, that is usually a question about internals and getting down to the implementation level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`weights.get` is a function that returns a value for the corresponding key in `weights`. When `max` looks for the largest value, it uses the return value of the `key` argument, passing in the input as an argument.

This code:

```
heaviest = max(weights, key=weights.get)
```

is equivalent to:

```
heaviest = max(weights, key=lambda k: weights.get(k))
```

or even more explicitly:

```
def fetchVal(key):
    return weights.get(key) # same as weights[key]

heaviest = max(weights, key=fetchVal)
```

When you pass `weights` into `max`, it iterates over the keys of the dictionary. Basically, with `max(weights, key=weights.get)`, you are saying: Give me the maximum key of `weights`; however, instead of using the value of the key itself to determine the max, use the corresponding value in `weights`.

Answer (score 2):

`d.get(k)` simply returns the value in the dictionary for the key `k`.

When you iterate over a dictionary, the iterator returns the dictionary keys. So for each dictionary, `max` calls `d.get(key)` to get the values to compare with each other. is equivalent to `d[key]`, so it returns the corresponding dictionary element.

Finally, `max` returns the key that corresponds to the maximum of all these values.

The code you gave is equivalent to:

```
foo = max(d, key = lambda k: d[k])
```

Comment: This would make perfect sense, but I did not use d.get(key), I used d.get, which I supposed is where my confusion comes from. Also - I found this piece of code on another stackoverflow question so I just wanted to understand how it worked before I continued relying on it. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how the `key` parameter works. The `max` function calls it on each element returned by the iterator.

Comment: The `max` function calls `d.get(key)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as much the get method as the max function "key=" argument, which takes a function as an argument.
When you tell it
    max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)

It iterates over the keys of my_dict, passes each dictionary key to the function given in the key= argument. And returns the key for which the function output was the highest.

```
max(my_dict, key=lambda k:my_dict[k])
```

Would do the same.